# EF Code First Modelbuilder creating unique identifiers where it should not

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionHistory>()
                .HasOptional(history => history.Sender)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(s => s.MapKey("Sender"))
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionHistory>()
                .HasOptional(history => history.Receiver)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(s => s.MapKey("Receiver"))
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

And in my table TransactionHistory, it creates unique identifiers at columns Sender and Receiver. I don't want those columns to be unique, what do i do?

TransactionHistory model:

```
public class TransactionHistory
    {
        public Account Sender { get; set; }
        public Account Receiver { get; set; }
    }
```

**Edit: Ok. Apparently uniqueidentifiers are not the case. The problem is, that when i am adding transactionhistory item into database, i got the following error:**

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Accounts'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Accounts'.\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated.

An i add this item like that:

```
context.Transactions.Add(history);
context.savechanges();
```

(Transactions is a transactionhistory object)

Comment: can you post your TransactionHistory model?  Specifically the way your sender and receiver properties.

Comment: when you say unique identifiers do you mean foreign keys to your Account table?

Comment: @Ben Tidman: No. I look up in my database, and those columns are unique identifiers. And that means i cant put two the same accounts in one column. And i need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity framework works by storing a cache of a bunch of objects in DBContext.  Even if all the properties are the same on your Account object (including your pk) entity framework will see this as a new object unless you remind it "hey, you already know about this".  I can think of 2 ways to do this:

```
context.Entry(history.Sender).State = EntityState.Modified; 
context.Entry(history.Receiver).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

or

Make sure when you set the Accounts on your history object that they are already attached to your dbcontext.

```
var sender = context.Accounts.FirstOfDefault(...your condition here...);
var receiver = context.Accounts.FirstOfDefault(...your condition here...);

history.Sender = sender;
history.Receiver = receiver;
```

Also EF does not load navigation/related entities unless you tell it to.  So if you are editing history make sure you using [.Include()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) to pull in your related objects.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well i don't see the difference? There is only added a bracket {} in .Map and .WillCascadeOnDelete() cut out. It doesn't change anything. My columns are still marked as uniqueidentifiers. :/

Comment: Wait a second. I was wrong. All my colums in my database that are pointing at something are uniqueidentifiers. So that's not the case.. Sorry, i will update my main post and tell what the problem is.

Comment: Ok. It works. It's werid as hell for me but im too tired today to look up further into it, will need to google up some more info about this. Thank you for helping me. :-)

Comment: Sure thing here is a blog that talks about it some:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx

Answer (score 2):

EF uses `uniqueidentifier` as SQL column type for the foreign keys because the principal's (= `Account`s) primary key is a `uniqueidentifier` - in C# it is a `Guid`, like `public Guid AccountId { get; set; }`.

It must choose this type because principal and dependent key types must match in a foreign key relationship in the database.

This does not mean that the foreign key column is unique (or has a unique index). Of course you can use the same `uniqueidentifier` value multiple times as the foreign key column value.